# Protractor/node versions compatibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor for e2e testing and grunt-task-runner package to run tests.

In my `package.json` file I have:

```
{
  ...,
  "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.1.2",
  ...,
  "protractor": "^2.5.1",
  ...
}
```

And in my `protractorConfig.js` I use `framework: 'jasmine2'`

My intent is to use protractor 2.5.1 + grunt-protractor-runner 2.1.2 for node version 0.12.9, and to use protractor 3.0.0 + grunt-protractor-runner 3.0.0 for node version >=4.x.

The fact is, that when I run npm install either using node version 0.12.9 or 5.4.1, I always have the same protractor version in node_modules folder - 2.5.1 and corresponding grunt-protractor-runner.

What am I doing wrong? 
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [`engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) field:

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=0.12.9 < 4" } }
```

But I don't think you can specify different versions of packages to install depending on the Node version.

Comment: You are right. I don't know why, but I thought that ^ or ~ give an opportunity to use compatible with nodejs versions of packages, but  now I understand that it uses compatible with specified by ME version, like in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json